make master/slave ip in different subnet
For reference, this is a follow-up and variation on group ip address to different subnet with shell
We have two strings (named master/slave), the two strings are composed with IPS spread in three subnets. Just need to make the two strings into pairs where the two addresses in each pair are in different /24 subnets. The following is an example:
Both master/slave have five IPS and spread in three subnets
172.28.250/172.28.154/172.28.254.
masters='172.28.250.99 172.28.250.101 172.28.154.41 172.28.154.52 172.28.254.30'
slaves='172.28.250.103 172.28.250.104 172.28.154.53 172.28.254.32 172.28.254.33'

Final output will create pairs like below:
the left side is from slaves, the right side is from masters, and for each pair, the first three sections are different, for 172.28.154.53 => 172.28.250.99  ,172.28.154 is different from 172.28.250
The output is not unique, what we want just make master /slave in different subnet
172.28.154.53  → 172.28.250.99
172.28.250.103 → 172.28.154.41
172.28.250.104 → 172.28.254.30
172.28.254.32  → 172.28.250.101
172.28.254.33  → 172.28.154.52

And I have tried the code as Stephane suggested like below,
we can push all ips into hash and make the pair to generated a map,but the output will make one ip from master match with another one from master,this is not expected output
perl -e '
  push @{$s{s/\.\d+$//r}}, $_ for @ARGV;
  @l = values %s;
  for ($n = @ARGV; $n > 0; $n -= 2) {
    @l = sort {@$b <=> @$a} @l;
    printf "%s %s\n", pop(@{$l[0]}), pop(@{$l[1]});
  }' $masters $slaves


With this code the out put is
172.28.250.104 172.28.254.33
172.28.250.103 172.28.154.53
172.28.250.101 172.28.154.52
172.28.254.32 172.28.250.99
172.28.254.30 172.28.154.41

We can see 172.28.250.103 172.28.154.53 both from masters, it's not what we need.

You need to explain how you pass the variables to your script and what's wrong with the code. Is there error or what is unexpected? What is the variable $nodes ?

$nodes is $masters $slaves,with this code,the output will take an ip from masters pair with another ip still from master,not what we want

You issue looks too specific. You should reduce/abstract. Please, read How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example.

Please [edit] your question to explain in terms of the values of fields in each of your 2 input variables why the expected output includes 172.28.154.53 => 172.28.250.99 but not 172.28.154.53 => 172.28.250.101 or various other combinations.

Only five values in the list? Well, that's only 120 permutations, and there are a couple of dozen acceptable ones, that sounds like good odds...
#!/bin/bash

masters='172.28.250.99 172.28.250.101 172.28.154.41 172.28.154.52 172.28.254.30'
slaves='172.28.250.103 172.28.250.104 172.28.154.53 172.28.254.32 172.28.254.33'

set -o noglob

# word-split to arrays, count
M=( $masters )
S=( $slaves )
n=${#M[@]}

try() {
    S=( $(printf '%s\n' "${S[@]}" | sort -R) )

    for (( i = 0; i < n; i++ )); do
        # remove last dot and everything past it
        M_subnet=${M[i]%.*}
        S_subnet=${S[i]%.*}
        if [ "$M_subnet" = "$S_subnet" ]; then
            # oops, that didn't work
            return 1
        fi
    done
    return 0
}

retries=0
until try; do
    (( ++retries ))
done

printf "%d retries later:\n" "$retries"
for (( i = 0; i < n; i++ )); do
    printf "%-15s -> %-15s\n" "${S[i]}" "${M[i]}"
done

Output (an example, by necessity):
% bash  pairup.sh
4 retries later:
172.28.154.53   -> 172.28.250.99
172.28.254.33   -> 172.28.250.101
172.28.254.32   -> 172.28.154.41
172.28.250.103  -> 172.28.154.52
172.28.250.104  -> 172.28.254.30

I suppose you guessed what sort -R does. I think the code should be clear enough. I feel I should be sorry for posting this, but... um, I'm not. Sorry about that.

While that eventually works, doing a deterministic search might feel a bit saner. If you have Python, there's itertools.permutations to help with that. So:
% cat pairup.py
#!/usr/bin/python3

import itertools
import re
import sys

M = sys.argv[1].split();
S = sys.argv[2].split();

def verify(M, Sx):
    for m, s in zip(M, Sx):
        if re.sub('\.[0-9]*$', '', m) == re.sub('\.[0-9]*$', '', s):
            return False
    return True

for Sx in itertools.permutations(S):
    if verify(M, Sx):
        break
else:
    print("uh, oh, no acceptable permutation found")
    exit(1)


for m, s in zip(M, Sx):
    print(s, "->", m)


and output:
% masters='172.28.250.99 172.28.250.101 172.28.154.41 172.28.154.52 172.28.254.30'
% slaves='172.28.250.103 172.28.250.104 172.28.154.53 172.28.254.32 172.28.254.33'
% python3 pairup.py "$masters" "$slaves"
172.28.154.53 -> 172.28.250.99
172.28.254.32 -> 172.28.250.101
172.28.250.103 -> 172.28.154.41
172.28.254.33 -> 172.28.154.52
172.28.250.104 -> 172.28.254.30


This did solved my problem,actually,we don't care about the performance regarding this.I'd like to buy you a cup of coffee.Thanks a lot.

@pengxiao, if you can use Python, the perhaps a bit saner deterministic approach turned out to be rather simple, see edit.

Oh, I didn't see Stéphane posted the same solution in Perl already, well.

If your sort has -R, chances are the system will have GNU shuf as well, then shuffling $S would just be S=( $(shuf -e -- "${S[@]}") ).

Python is no problem for me,and we just need to install related python libs.We just use this script to finish some automation jobs.Thanks all for your help!

A brute-force approach would be to try all the permutations of either one of the two lists until you find one where all the IP address pairs are in different subnets.
Using the Algorithm::Permute perl module:
perl -MAlgorithm::Permute=permute -e '
  # split list on blanks and break down into /24 subnet and last byte
  @slave  = map [/(.*)\.(.*)/], split " ", shift;
  @master = map [/(.*)\.(.*)/], split " ", shift;
  $n = @master;
  permute {
    for ($i = 0; $i < $n; $i++) {
      # not a match if same subnet
      return if $slave[$i]->[0] eq $master[$i]->[0];
    }
    # That is a match
    for ($i = 0; $i < $n; $i++) {
      printf "%s.%s => %s.%s\n", @{$slave[$i]}, @{$master[$i]};
    }
    exit;
  } @master;
  die "Not matchable\n"' -- "$slaves" "$masters"

Which here gives:
172.28.250.103 => 172.28.154.52
172.28.250.104 => 172.28.254.30
172.28.154.53 => 172.28.250.99
172.28.254.32 => 172.28.250.101
172.28.254.33 => 172.28.154.41


Stephane,I can't use extendedglob in bash,is it possible to implement this with bash?

I'm sorry to requst your help several times,as I really can't solve it by myself.

No, that syntax is zsh-specific (not only the extendedglob option), and zsh has no equivalent to most of the features used there. If in bash, use zsh -c 'that whole code', but I'm not sure why anyone would use bash in this day and age when they can have zsh for the same price.

We are using centos,can only run bash,and can we implement this with perl?maybe it's more simple

@pengxiao, zsh like bash has been used on Unix-like systems since before Linux even existed, it's packaged in virtually all Linux distributions, CentOS included. perl would be definitely a lot more adequate than bash, but there are features of zsh that make it quite  easy here (see edit). A perl (or awk) variant would likely be longer and more effort. I'll try and translate it to perl later if I have a moment.

Stephane,there is an error with 3 masters/3 slaves,really a difficult issue.masters='192.28.34.48 192.28.33.95 192.28.32.163'
slaves='192.28.33.94 192.28.34.46 192.28.32.162'

we just need to do a loop,list all conditions,when some lines meet the requirement,then break and exit,then it's ok –

@pengxiao, yes, sorry the approach was completely flawed. See edit for one that just tries all combinations until one fits.

It's not clear why the expected output should be that specific output you show rather than some other set of pairs. If you just want pairs of IP addresses in slaves along with those in masters with a different subnet value then that could be the following using any awk:
#!/usr/bin/env bash

masters='172.28.250.99 172.28.250.101 172.28.154.41 172.28.154.52 172.28.254.30'
slaves='172.28.250.103 172.28.250.104 172.28.154.53 172.28.254.32 172.28.254.33'

awk -v ss="$slaves" -v ms="$masters" '
    BEGIN {
        split(ss,slaveIps)
        split(ms,masterIps)
        for (i in slaveIps) {
            slaveSn = slaveIps[i]
            sub(/\.[^.]+$/,"",slaveSn)
            for (j in masterIps) {
                masterSn = masterIps[j]
                sub(/\.[^.]+$/,"",masterSn)
                if ( slaveSn != masterSn ) {
                    print slaveIps[i], "=>", masterIps[j]
                }
            }
        }
    }
'


$ ./tst.sh
172.28.250.103 => 172.28.154.41
172.28.250.103 => 172.28.154.52
172.28.250.103 => 172.28.254.30
172.28.250.104 => 172.28.154.41
172.28.250.104 => 172.28.154.52
172.28.250.104 => 172.28.254.30
172.28.154.53 => 172.28.250.99
172.28.154.53 => 172.28.250.101
172.28.154.53 => 172.28.254.30
172.28.254.32 => 172.28.250.99
172.28.254.32 => 172.28.250.101
172.28.254.32 => 172.28.154.41
172.28.254.32 => 172.28.154.52
172.28.254.33 => 172.28.250.99
172.28.254.33 => 172.28.250.101
172.28.254.33 => 172.28.154.41
172.28.254.33 => 172.28.154.52


Ed,This one helps,I will filter the duplicate ones to get the final results.Thanks

the final output will only 5 records,the 5 ones in left side are unique,and the five ones on right ones are unique

I filter the duplicate records,not so elegant,but can get what we need
I just edit your reply,thanks

That code you added in an edit wouldn't work (and if it did it would be extremely slow to run so we wouldn't write it using multiple bash loops with associative arrays like that anyway). If you want the minimum set of unique combinations that covers all values then you need to write code to carefully decide which pairs to select, you can't just pick the first 5 or less with unique IPs after pairing.

For example, if you have a b; a c; d b as your 3 pairs output by my script, then if you pick and print a b as your first pair then with your algorithm you'd discard a c since a had already been seen and discard d b since b had been seen so you'd never see c or d in your output, it'd only be a b, but if you instead pick a c first then you can also print d b and so your output would be a c; d b, i.e. would include all 4 IPs.
